# Htaccess get last word after last slash

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I get

```
http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=ccc
```

also want that it should work in cases like

```
http://www.example.com/aaa
http://www.example.com/aaa/
```

which will be

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=aaa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/?     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php      [NC]
RewriteRule  .*      /index.php?cat=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Maps silently:

`http://www.example.com/any/number/of/folders/LastFolder`

To:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=LastFolder`

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,NC,QSA]` with `[R=301,L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: Seems it is not working for www.example.com/aaa   ...URL not found. But working for www.example.com/aaa/bbb

Comment: Yes. I can see why. Will modify my answer.

Comment: Seems its working with one little flaw. After I started using your htaccess(even before your edit), the images and css on page wont load...its just plain text...do you know, where could be a problem?

Comment: Its because of htaccess, when i delete it on the server, css and images will load

Comment: The rule-set in my answer does what you asked for. You wanted to redirect the 1st level URL tree (Root) where usually those files are, it is doing it: `www.example.com/aaa `

Comment: Well I am extremely inexperienced with htaccess so it might not give a sense what I am going to say now, but isnt it redirecting the XX level (e.g. 1,2,3,4) to level 1 what I wanted, not the opposite?

Comment: Not exactly. The fact is everything is being redirected to `/index.php`, independent of the rule-set conditions and even when the last level in the URL directory structure is the 1st level in the directory tree under public_html. There are no exceptions.

Comment: So how should i set up my css exactly? Tried putting absolute paths and base tags in many ways but not a single have worked.

Comment: Modified my answer to exclude from the rule existing files. Please give it a try.

Comment: Its better! Now the css works for: example.com/aaa, but 2nd level still not working: example.com/aaa/bbb

Comment: You mean it is not redirecting to `index.php?cat=bbb` or the CSS file is not working when the incoming URL is `xample.com/aaa/bbb`? If this is the case, what happens with `example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc, etc.`?

Comment: its just CSS problem...redirecting to index.php?cat=xxx is working fine.  CSS work only on example.com/aaaa, when you go deeper like example.com/aaaa/bbb, aaa/bbb/ccc or even aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd, its not working.

Comment: Okay. There should not be any difference as it is mapping to the same resource and I guess there is only one CSS file. Are there more, one at each page? If there aren't, make sure the links in the PHP script are like this `http://example.com/mycss.css`, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: when I set CSS like you have written, it is all working except images, which are working only for example.com/aaa but not any deeper. Since background images for divs were working and the problem was only with images within <img> tag, I set the <base> tag to my domain and now everything is working on any level. I only hope there wont be problem with javascript, which I am going to add  since the javascript iteself usualy include a lot of images and other scripts( i am talking about things like lightbox, coin slider and so).

Do you know what was causing the problem?